# Casting column inside CASE is not supported

Tags: casting, abap, cds

I want to make a new field in my CDS-View, with a CASE-condition as below

```
case  
  when usage  = 0 then '1'
  when usage < '10' or usage_6m > '0' then '2'
  when usage < '250' or usage_6m > '10' then '3'
  else '0'
end as usage
```

The problem is that the type of the field "usage" NUMC10 is, so eclipse throws an error : "data type conflict". So then I wanted to cast the field to abap.int4, but that does not work eighter, because the CAST--expression is not supported:

```
case 
        when cast( usage  as abap.int4 )  = 0 then '1'
...
```

Experts please advise how can i solve this, why I can not cast a field inside of a CASE-expression.

regards,
Umar Abdullah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also compare the NUMC values directly. The help article "ABAP CDS - cond_expr, Comparable Types", says that NUMC can be compared to other NUMC literals with the relational operators >, < etc. if the field and literal have the exact same length.

Meaning you need to change this for your NUMC(10) to:

```
case  
  when usage = '0000000000' then '1'
  when usage < '0000000010' or usage_6m > '0' then '2'
  when usage < '0000000250' or usage_6m > '10' then '3'
  else '0'
end as usage
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a second CDS view underneath:

```
define view <lower_view> as select from <table> {
    cast( usage as abap.int4 ) as usage;
    cast( usage_6m as abap.int4 ) as usage_6m;
}

define view <upper_view> as select from <lower_view> {
    case 
        when usage = 0 then '1'
        when usage < 10 or usage_6m > 0 then '2'
        when usage < 250 or usage_6m > 10 then '3'
        else '0'
    end as usage 
}
```

`usage` is a reserved word. The compiler will reject naming a column like that.

Comment: usage is as example here. You can try with other than reserved word.